# CSS: How to create a button with an arrow placedo on the right

Tags: css

I need to reproduce following button:

[image]

I have already tried to create it, but the arrow on the right is not the same as in the picture. How can I reproduce the same white arrow?

```
.sBtn {
 display: inline-block;
 background: #908589;
 border: 0;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 1.2em;
letter-spacing: 0.04em;
line-height: 2.5em;
padding: 0 0 0 1em;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
margin-top: 14px;

 }

...and so on...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jobgaraux/h81z00jL/1/

Comment: ⏵= `&#9205;` you can use unicode characters and set `color:white;` in your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made it for you [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h81z00jL/2/)

Edited HTML:

```
<span class="arrowBtn">&nbsp;<span class="icon"></span></span>
```

You can create CSS3 arrow from borders:

```
.sBtn-go .arrowBtn .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 13px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
}
```

Comment: Hi debute
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Daniel you are welcome! Note that `border-width: 15px 0 15px 13px;` can change the size of arrow, both 15px values are for height and last 13px value is for width. But this can be applied just to the arrow pointing right. You can play with it on this website: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Answer (score 1):

may be this will help youl

```css
.sBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #908589;
  border: 0;
        color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 14px;
   
    }

  .arrowBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 2.5em;
    transition: margin 200ms;
    margin-left: .75em;
    position:relative;
    left:2px;
  }



.sBtn-go .arrowBtn {
    background-color: #B6AFB1;
  }
  .sBtn-go .arrowBtn:hover {
    }
   .sBtn-go .arrowBtn {
      background-color: desaturate(darken(#F8AD6C,5%),5%);
    }
```

```html
<button class="sBtn sBtn-go" name="search">Search<span class="arrowBtn">&#x25BA</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #908589;
  border: 0;
        color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 14px;
   
    }

  .arrowBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 2.5em;
    transition: margin 200ms;
    margin-left: .75em;
  }



.sBtn-go .arrowBtn {
    background-color: #B6AFB1;
  }
  .sBtn-go .arrowBtn:hover {
    }
   .sBtn-go .arrowBtn {
      background-color: desaturate(darken(#F8AD6C,5%),5%);
    }
```

```html
<button class="sBtn sBtn-go" name="search">Search<span class="arrowBtn">&#x25BA</span></button>
```